# inotify - cannot add a watch to newly created directory after few levels in a directory tree

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems

I am using inotify on Linux to monitor a directory. My directory has 50 sub-directories and my directory tree is 20 level deep. I am able to monitor directory and all its sub directories till this point. I using C++ STL vector to save each directories path and their respective watch descriptor. When i add 8 or 10 new directories recursively i.e. add new 8-10 new level, i get notification about any event till 28th or 30th levels inside the directory tree. If i create a new directory inside 28th or 30th level than i do not get any notification.

Has any body faced this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should add some debugging information to your application to display the number of watches that are created. Maybe you are reaching the number of inotify watches limit.

You can query the `max_user_watches` value with `sysctl`:

```
$ sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 8192
```

I also suggest that you examine the return value of `inotify_add_watch()` in your program. It may return `ENOSPC` if the user limit on the total number of watches is reached or `ENAMETOOLONG` if the path name is tool long (that may happen since you create a deep directory tree).